# Access denied or 403 when loading image styles for private managed files

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a custom entity that uploads files through the managed files setting and the private method. The upload works fine. However when I try to display the images in my templates or if I access them through the url generated by Drupal I get a 403 access denied.

So here is what I am doing:

```
/* @ demo_patient_weight.module */

/* First I get the current user */
$userCurrent = \Drupal::currentUser(); 
$userCurrentID = $userCurrent->id();

/* I load the data (list of ids) of my entity which is called demo_patient_weight */
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('demo_patient_weight')->condition('user_id', $userCurrentID);
$entity_ids = $query->execute();

/* Loop through the ids and get the uploaded images */
$count = 0;
foreach($entity_ids as $entity_id) {
    $count++;
    $patient = entity_load('demo_patient_weight', $entity_id);
    // Get the file uri, weight_photo is the name of the field that uploads
    $file_uri = $patient->weight_photo->entity->getFileUri();
    $file_path = \Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle::load('medium')->buildUri($file_uri);
    // Assign the file path to a variable that twig can use in a <img /> tag
    $vars["page"]["patient_image"] = $file_path;
}


/* @ page--patient--weight.html.twig */
/* The code below gives me a 403 access denied for the image */
<img src="{{ page.patient_image }}" />
```

In the end I get a link like: /system/files/styles/medium/private/weight_photos/patient_0.png?itok=BAIbyx_X

And in my developer tools shows as 403 access denied. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the user/role for each? As in, for the private file system is the user/role the same as the user/role for the web server?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, in the system settings the private folders is owned by apache and the web server runs with that user also if that is what you mean.